# as many threads as process

Tags: multithreading, qt

I need to call this external command "qconf" from my application without freezing it where

```
queueList = ["all.q","a1.q","a2.q","a3.q"]
```

I found that this can be done using threads. How ?

Is there another way

command is

```
qconf -sq all.q
```

Comment: Why don't you stick to the old thread.

Comment: The unedited version of this question seems to make a little more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  QtConcurrent will optimize the thread count.

```
void executeInProcess(QString& text)
{
    QProcess::execute( "qconf", QStringList() << "-sq" <<  text);
}

void main()
{

    QApplication app;
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    //...
    QStringList queueList;
    QFutureWatcher watcher; 
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &mainWindow, SLOT(whatEverYouWantToDo()));
    QFuture<void> result = QtConcurrent::map(queueList, executeInProcess);
    watcher.setFuture(result);
    //...
    app.exec();
}
```

### Edit

If you want result from every process you need the mapped function  `QFuture<T> mapped ( const Sequence & sequence, MapFunction function )`  and executeInProcess needs to return the result from the `QProcess` call.

```
QString executeInProcess(QString& text)
{
    QString result;
    QProcess::execute( "qconf", QStringList() << "-sq" <<  text);
    // ... 
    return 
}
```

in `whatEverYouWantToDo()` you can iterate over the results

```
QFuture<QString> result ;
QFutureIterator<QString> i(result);
while (i.hasNext()) {    
    qDebug() << i.next();
}
```

Comment: From the code you have suggested, this is what i understand. kindly crosscheck

1) QStringList queueList; contains all.q, a1.q, a2.q, a3.q such that when the line 
QFuture<void> result = QtConcurrent::map(queueList, executeInProcess); runs it will run for all the items in the queueList and whatever I need to do with the result of each executeInProcess, I need to mention that in whatEverYouWantToDo() function. In other words, the code you have mentioned here will completely take care of the looping thru the queueList without a for loop. Kindly ascertain.

2)

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried the code u suggested on top. QFuture gives an output after all the items in the sequence of QtConcurrent::map(sequenceList,functionF) is exhausted. However, what i need is that, within each call to the functionF, that I, be able to start a process, get its result in a file, modify it, save the file and use another process to throw it back into the system. Here I would need a class that will ensure that only after one process has completed that the following ones will follow

Comment: @knishua What do you need?  You have a list of strings and want to processed the items sequential or parallel?  What do you mean by throw it back to the process?

Comment: Tim, 
i have a list of string and want to process it such that
a) functionF will call external command qprocess:start("qconf -sq listL[i]") 
b) the output of this will be stored in /tmp/tempfile.txt 
c) this file is modified and saved 
d) functionF calls external comm "qconf -Mq /tmp/tempfile.txt" 

at present step d should start only after step a b and c have completed.  :)


proc->setStandardOutputFile("/tmp/tempfile.txt")  is used to set the output